# Re-ordering ggplot2 legend (time series)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, timeserieschart

After spending most of a day looking for solutions i don't seem to figure this out, even after reading a LOT of posts about it.

Making a time series graph with 3 lines (link to graph bellow, please click), the legend reads (from top to bottom) BR Def, BR Grow and BR Mod but i want it to read (from top to bottom) BR Def, BR Mod and BR Grow.

I guess the perfect way would be to reorder the factor levels but i seem to not be able to.

```
MF <- read_csv(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LuisSousaSilva/",
                      "Articles-and-studies/master/MF.csv"), 
               col_types = cols(BR_Def = col_number(), 
                                BR_Grow = col_number(), BR_Mod = col_number(), 
                                Date = col_date(format = "%Y-%m-%d")))

ggplot(MF, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = BR_Def, colour ='BR Def')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = BR_Mod, colour ='BR Mod')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = BR_Grow, colour ='BR Grow'))
```

[Link to Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueSxn.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I made some changes to make it more clear but i don't know how much clearer i can be as in my mind i see the question as correctly stated. English is not my main language and some problems can arise. Can you please tell me what you can't figure out? The problem is just re-ordering of the legend in the ggplot2 chart as ggplot2 doesn't respect the way the dataframe columns are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to tidy up the data somewhat, so that all the data is in one variable, with another variable indicating which of the 3 categories each of the data points refer to. That variable should be a factor, and use  `forcats::fct_relevel` to set the order you want it to appear in the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

MF <- MF %>% 
  gather(key = categories, value = values, -Date) %>% 
  mutate(categories = categories %>% 
           factor() %>% 
           fct_relevel("BR_Def", "BR_Mod"))

ggplot(MF, aes(x = Date, y = values, colour = categories)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]